# Call to undefined method CI_Loader::template() when move to hosting server

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined-function

I am using CI 3 and all functions area working in my local server.

But when i uploaded it to the webhosting server it give me this error:

```
  Call to undefined method CI_Loader::template()
```

My controller  "Main.php" has the code:

```
 class Main extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();                  
        /* enable session */            
        //$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);             
    }

    public function index() {
        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/admin/main.php'))
        {
            /* Whoops, we don't have a page for that! */
            show_404();
        }


        $data['menu'] = $this->load->view('templates/menu', $data, TRUE);                           
        $data['title'] = "EGB | Main"; 
        $this->load->template('admin/main', $data);

        //$this->load->view('admin/main', $data);                                   
    }
 }
```

And in the "My_Loader.php" has:

```
 class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {
    public function template($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
         if($return):
            $content  = $this->view('templates/header', $vars, $return);
            $content .= $this->view($template_name, $vars, $return);
            $content .= $this->view('templates/footer', $vars, $return);

            return $content;
        else:
            $this->view('templates/header', $vars);
            $this->view($template_name, $vars);
            $this->view('templates/footer', $vars);
        endif;
    }
}
```

What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with the file name `MY_Loader.php` instead of `My_Loader.php`

Comment: Yeah ur right ! I missed on that ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your core file names should match the class name.

Try changing the file name to

> core/**MY_Loader.php**

Instead of

> core/**My_Loader.php**

Answer (score 1):

It has to be

> MY_Loader.php

only. The prefix is fixed.